# Esconder DIV somente no IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

estou com uma pequena duvida, como faço para esconder uma div (.laser) somente no IE8?

Preferencialmente gostaria de usa somente CSS ou também JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um arquivo `.css` chamado, por exemplo, `ie.css`. Faça a chamada dele no cabeçalho da sua página/site/aplicação da seguinte maneira:

```
<!--[if lte IE 8]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Dentro dele, basta esconder a `div` como você normalmente faria:

```
.laser{
    display: none;
}
```

Todas as regras dentro deste arquivo serão aplicadas apenas nas versões do IE 8 ou anteriores.

Se você quiser atingir outras versões do IE ou uma gama delas, [eis uma excelente referência](https://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/).

Comment: Este exemplo funciona para todas as anteriores ao 8.  Caso fossem todos os IEs, a condição seria `<!--[if IE]>`

Comment: Você está certo, desculpe a falta de atenção, já removi o comentário

Comment: @CaioFelipePereira muito obrigado mesmo!! deu certo aqui. Talvez voê me tire outra duvida, como faria para funcionar o radios em IE8 - desculpe essa outra pergunta mais você parece dominar cross browser, rs!! v

Comment: @DaviVoltas, se você tem outra dúvida, faça uma nova pergunta. Dessa maneira, a informação fica mais bem distribuída, facilitando para outros que possam ter as mesmas dúvidas que você.